# Jira is not working with https [SSL]

Tags: apache, tomcat, jira

We can able to load the application using below URL [Tomcat],
http://12.12.12.12:8080

But the application is not loading up with the https://12.12.12.12:8080

So we enable the ssl on server.xml file with the port 8443, after that the application is directly redirecting to apache home page not with the application home page.

http is redirecting to https [but redirection home page is wrong]

Comment: How you configured your server.xml File? are you able to access via https://12.12.12.12:8443 ?

Comment: Yes we can able to access the access the 12.12.12.12:8443, but it's redirecting to Apache home page instead of Jira home page. But 12.12.12.12:8080 perfectly redirecting to Jira home page.